# Sorting Array in iphone SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting

In my app, I have two arrays names `listofevents` & `arr_Distance`.

**Listofevents look like following:**

```
(
    {
        Latitude = "34.1356031";
        Longitude = "-118.0312634";
        VenueName = "Fantasia Billiard";
    }, {
        Latitude = "34.1356031";
        Longitude = "-118.0312634";
        VenueName = "Dave & Busters";
    }
)
```

**arr_distace look like**

`( 54985.5455,54985.5455 )`

I have calculate the distance as per Latitude & Longitude given in JSON Response. Here,i want show the list in increasing order of distance, so i sorted the two array as per following code

**For Sorting**

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:listOfEvents forKeys:arr_distance];
sortedArray = [arr_distance sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
sortedValues = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *key in sortedArray) {
    [sortedValues addObject:[dict valueForKey:key]];
}
```

**Problem**

But my Problem is that when the two distances are same & venue Names are different, then It **shows me only first venue Name Two Times.**

I didn't found my Problem. Help me to solve this Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code. I have slightly modified my earlier solution to avoid the usage of dictionary. The earlier suggestion of dictionary was purely based on the assumption that key will be unique which is not the case now it seems. So you can try this:

```
NSArray *a = @[@"353.90", @"354.68", @"354.68", @"1.18"];
NSArray *b = @[@{ @"Contestant1":@"Jon jones1",
    @"Contestant2":@"Anderson silva1"},
      @{ @"Contestant1":@"Jon jones2",
         @"Contestant2":@"Anderson silva2"},
      @{ @"Contestant1":@"Jon jones3",
         @"Contestant2":@"Anderson silva3"},
      @{ @"Contestant1":@"Jon jones4",
         @"Contestant2":@"Anderson silva4"}];

NSArray *sortedArray = [a sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch];
}];

NSArray *sortedValues = [b sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {

    id obj1 = [a objectAtIndex:[b indexOfObject:firstObject]];
    id obj2 = [a objectAtIndex:[b indexOfObject:secondObject]];

    return [((NSString *)obj1) compare:((NSString *)obj2) options:NSNumericSearch];
}];

NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
NSLog(@"%@",sortedValues);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! yes, its working! But can you just explain me what is the problem previously?

Comment: @user1673099, As I mentioned in answer, that solution was based on the assumption that the first array has all unique values. When you create a dictionary with duplicate keys, it will accept only the last key. So your first one will get overwritten and the value will be always the one corresponding to second one. That was what happened in your case. You always got the second value instead of first one.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the distances as keys, but each key needs to be unique. As you have identical distances, the later object to the key will overwrite the first.

I thing the best solution would be to create a custom class, that holds each entry
you could also add a property `distance`and sort by it.

```
@interface Entry : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString *longitude
@property (strong) NSString *latitude
@property (strong) NSString *name
@property double distance;
@end
```

do

```
NSMutableArray *listOfEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
[listofevents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Entry *entry = [[Entry alloc] init];
    entry.latitude = [dict objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
    entry.longitude = [dict objectForKey:@"Longitude"];
    entry.name = [dict objectForKey:@"VenueName"];
    entry.distance = DistanceBetweenPoints(currentLocation, CGPointMake(entry.latitude,entry.longitude));
    [listOfEntries addObject:entry];
}];


[listOfEntries sortUsingComparator:
      ^NSComparisonResult(Entry *obj1, Entry *obj2){
            return obj1.distance > obj2.distance;
    }
];
```

---

Another option would be to have the name being the key in a dictionary.

Comment: I am getting error on DistanceBetweenPoints like in Compatible Pointer type.

Comment: it is your duty to calcualate the distance. I dont know, how your `DistanceBetweenPoints` looks like.

Comment: Thanks for reply!! okay, i try.Wait!

Comment: Are you just copy and pasting? that wont work often on stack overflow, as the browser doesnt syntax check and suggest code completion.

Comment: but sorry to say that i am not very familier with Block coding. How is it working?

Comment: it doesnt matter, if you use for-loop, fast enumeration of block enumeration. but I corrected my code.

Comment: I didn't do it. Any one did that. I am very thankful to you for your guidance.

Comment: Thanks @ACB, it means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is very simple. In a dictionary each key should be unique. In your case it's not.

Your keys : **54985.5455 and 54985.5455** , both are same. That's why the issue occurs. Change one of them, it'll work like a charm.

Comment: I know but is there any other solution??

Comment: @user1673099: use unique keys, if you need to use NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can perform search according to your result. I found following from apple

```
-(NSArray*)SortingArray:(NSMutableArray*)unSortedArray
{
    static NSStringCompareOptions compareOption=NSCaseInsensitiveSearch |NSNumericSearch|NSWidthInsensitiveSearch|NSForcedOrderingSearch;
    NSLocale *locale=[NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSComparator comparatorBlock=^(id  string1, id  string2)
    {
        NSRange string1Range=NSMakeRange(0,[string1 length]);
        return        [string1 compare:string2 options:compareOption range:string1Range locale:locale];
    };
    NSArray *sortedArray=[unSortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:comparatorBlock ];
    return sortedArray;
}
```

You can use your string compare options. There are more options for restricting search as I found

```
NSCaseInsensitiveSearch = 1,
NSLiteralSearch = 2,        /* Exact character-by-character equivalence */
NSBackwardsSearch = 4,      /* Search from end of source string */
NSAnchoredSearch = 8,       /* Search is limited to start (or end, if NSBackwardsSearch) of source string */
NSNumericSearch = 64,       /* Added in 10.2; Numbers within strings are compared using numeric value, that is, Foo2.txt < Foo7.txt < Foo25.txt; only applies to compare methods, not find */
NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch  /* If specified, ignores diacritics (o-umlaut == o) */
NSWidthInsensitiveSearch  /* If specified, ignores width differences ('a' == UFF41) */
NSForcedOrderingSearch  /* If specified, comparisons are forced to return either NSOrderedAscending or NSOrderedDescending if the strings are equivalent but not strictly equal, for stability when sorting (e.g. "aaa" > "AAA" with NSCaseInsensitiveSearch specified) */
NSRegularExpressionSearch    /* Applies to rangeOfString:..., stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:..., and replaceOccurrencesOfString:... methods only; the search string is treated as an ICU-compatible regular expression; if set, no other options can apply except NSCaseInsensitiveSearch and NSAnchoredSearch */
```