# Sorting Multiple NSMutableArray's

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have 3 MutableArray's Named:

- tvShows
- tvNetworks
- tvdbID

I need to sort them by the name of the tvShows.
But the need to stay linked.
So e.g.:

```
tvShows = Breaking Bad, House, Community;
tvNetworks = AMC, FOX, NBC;
tvdbID = 81189, 73255, 94571;
```

Needs To Become:

```
tvShows = Breaking Bad, Community, House;
tvNetworks = AMC, NBC, FOX;
tvdbID = 81189, 94571, 73255;
```

How would I do this? It's my first app so sorry if it's a realy easy question.

Comment: you can't with just three arrays. you have to link them... e.g. using a dictionary with the tv shows as keys

Comment: I tried that but it changed my MutableArray's in to NSArrays. Is there a way to not convert them?

Comment: if you really want to change a mutableArray into an array you can [[mutableArray copy]autorelease] them, but that isn't what you really want to do.

Comment: I would fix this at the source. Don't load 3 different arrays, but one JSON file with records [(tv, network, id), (..)]. That you can sort on the client and the fields are kept together.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15194914/1730272. Check the answer there.

Comment: Well the information is already comming from a JSON file but i cant change that one... And could you explain why i dont want to do the mutableArray copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest and most straightforward ways to do this would be to create *one* array of dictionaries, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *tvShowInfos = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < tvShows.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *info = @{@"show": [tvShows objectAtIndex:i],
                           @"network": [tvNetworks objectAtIndex:i],
                           @"id": [tvdbIDs objectAtIndex:i]};
    [tvShowInfos addObject:info];
}
```

You can then sort that array easily:

```
[tvShowInfos sortUsingDescriptors:@[ [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"show" ascending:YES] ]];
```

If you need an array that contains all networks, sorted by show title, you can then use `valueForKey:` on the array of dictionaries:

```
NSArray *networksSortedByShow = [tvShowInfos valueForKey:@"network"];
```

Comment: Pff... This worked thought I would never figure it out... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

store them in an array of dictionaries then sort with an NSArray sort function: (below)

```
NSDictionary * dict1 = @{@"title":@"breaking bad",@"network":@"AMC",@"tvbdID":@(81189)};
NSDictionary * dict2 = @{@"title":@"house",@"network":@"FOX",@"tvbdID":@(73255)};
NSDictionary * dict3 = @{@"title":@"Community",@"network":@"NBC",@"tvbdID":@(94571)};

NSArray * array = @[dict1,dict2,dict3];

NSSortDescriptor * desc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title"ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSArray * sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[desc]];
```

Comment: the code is confusing and incomplete but I think the proposed approach is good

Comment: the dicts should contain the other items so it makes sense

Answer (score 2):

I would personally create a custom NSObject called TVShow, that has properties of showName, network, and tvbdID. This way, you only have one array of each show. Assuming your array is called myShows, you could do something like this:

```
[allShows sortUsingComparitor:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString *firstName = [(TVShow*)a showName];
    NSString *secondName = [(TVShow*)b showName];
    return [firstName compare: secondName];
}];
```

That is, if you wanted to sort by show name. You can swap `network` for `showName` if you wanted to sort by network!

Comment: what... why is secondName an NSDate?

Comment: Ah sorry, copied from another example I had! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it with 3 independent arrays but maybe with 1 dictionary where the keys are tv shows and the value is a dictionary with 2 keys:  tvNetworks & tvdbIDs

sample:

```
NSDictionary *data = @{@"Breaking Bad":@{@"tv" : @"AMC", @"tvdb": @(81189)},
                       @"House":@{@"tv" : @"FOX", @"tvdb": @(73255)},
                       @"Community":@{@"tv" : @"NBC", @"tvdb": @(94571)}};

NSArray *sortedShows = [data.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

for (id show in sortedShows) {
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", show, data[show]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea what your end goal is, but you should probably create a TVShow class that has properties (i.e., instance variables) for "title," "network", and "dbid."  Then you can instantiate three TVShow objects with their appropriate properties, put them in a mutable array, and use one of the sorting methods on NSMutableArray -- I'd probably choose `sortUsingComparator:`.